# Execute SQL Query on aspx page

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Hello fellow programmers,

I'm really stuck with the simpliest things - i cannot find a way to solve my problem without using mvc.

Folder Structure:

```
project
-> App_Data
----> mviedb.mdf
-> Default.aspx
----> Default.aspx.cs
-> Web.config
```

My mviedb Database so far (table users):

```
id | user   | password 
---+--------+------------
1  | daniel | 1
2  | test   | test
```

What I want to do: basically print out what's in my table, so "select * from users" - yet i don't really know how. My Default.aspx.cs file:

```
namespace mvie {
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            string query = "select * from users";
            if (Query != "") {
                try {
                    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(query, @"data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\mviedb.mdf;User Instance=true");
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    adp.Fill(dt);

                } catch (Exception ex) {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

now i need to print the DataTable somewhere. But how? I googled for a while but was not able to find a solution without mvc.

Comment: Search for ASP.NET DataBinding and GridView ASPX control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Steve's comment, ASP.Net WebForms encourages you to use controls such as [`GridView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or a [`Repeater`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) when representing data in tabular fashion. This will then render the equivalent Html to the browser.

For example, inside the `<form runat="server">` tag in your `.aspx` file add the controls:

```
<asp:DataGrid runat="server" ID="gridUsers"></asp:DataGrid>
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblError"></asp:Label>
```

And in your code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        var query = "select * from users";
        try
        {
            // DataAdapters and DataTables are IDisposable
            using (var adp = new SqlDataAdapter(query, @"data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;...;"))
            using (var dt = new DataTable())
            {
                adp.Fill(dt);
                // Bind the datatable to the grid
                gridUsers.DataSource = dt;
                gridUsers.DataBind();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblError.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

Will render a very basic table showing all columns of your `users` table.

However, if you can, I would recommend that you leave WebForms (which is a legacy technology) and instead move ahead to ASP.Net MVC, where you will instead fetch the users data in a controller, and render the users table directly in a View. This way you have much finer control over the Html rendering.

Comment: Hi there. I know MVC handels a lot for you but I want to understand ASPX first. It's so unintuitive for me (usually derping around with php and mysql)

Edit: how do i link aspx and aspx.cs properly? getting the error that the aspx.cs file cannot find the Label and Grid

Comment: Start with a brand new blank Web Form - this should create the .aspx and .aspx.cs files for you (and in fact, on newer versions of Visual Studio there will also be an automagic .designer.cs). Then just add the above `<asp:DataGrid ` controls into the .aspx `html`, after the "<form runat="server">" element. VS should then create the control in the designer.cs for you.

Comment: Hi @StuartLC, I'm working with Visual Studio 2010 - so no designer for me (which i don't mind tbo). I created a new Project and working with `Default.aspx` and `Default.aspx.cs`, they should be linked, right?